# How do I stop my computer from auto-correcting brightness/gamma/contrast?

Tags: graphics-card, display, calibration, contrast, gamma

For some reason my computer tries to auto-adjust for brightness/gamma/contrast. This is really annoying because if I start viewing something a bit darker, say a dark webpage, the browser and Start Menu etc look odd.

I tried manually adjusting the settings in the Intel Graphics Properties - when I moved one of the sliders, the screen changes for maybe half a second but then the auto-adjust kicks in again, preventing me from properly calibrating.

What could possibly be causing this? I've looked all over the Control Panel for my i5 onboard graphics card and also my AMD 6490M (switchable graphics laptop), but I can't find anything to turn this feature off.

Comment: If it's a desktop, are you sure it's not the Monitor itself that does that?

Comment: Yes, it's a laptop.